# Como solucionar "Conversion failed when converting the varchar value to data type int"

Tags: sql-server, xml

Estoy teniendo problemas al obtener los valores de un XML con una consulta, al momento de ejecutar la consulta obtengo como error lo siguiente:

```
Conversion failed when converting the varchar value ';#Alexander Pierce;#Sarah Ross;#Adam Jones;#' to data type int.
```

La consulta que estoy usando para obtener estos valores del campo `tp_ColumnSet` que es donde se almacena el XML es la siguiente:

```
SELECT T.Titulo     Titulo,
            ASG.AsignadoSG AsignadoSG,
            ASG.tp_ID ClaveAsignadoSG
    FROM        (Select tp_ColumnSet.value('(/nvarchar1)[1]', 'nvarchar(100)') Titulo,
                        tp_ColumnSet.value('(/nvarchar4)[1]', 'nvarchar(100)') Estado,                      
                        tp_ColumnSet.value('(/ntext4)[1]', 'varchar(max)')  AsignadoSG
                From WSS_Content.dbo.UserData   
                Where tp_ListId = 'C4B4B8A8' )  T
    LEFT JOIN (SELECT tp_ID,
            tp_ColumnSet.value('(/nvarchar1)[1]', 'nvarchar(100)') AsignadoSG 
            FROM WSS_Content.DBO.UserData WHERE tp_ListId = '176A5B63') ASG ON ASG.tp_ID = T.AsignadoSG     
    Where   T.Estado in ('Iniciada', 'En Curso')
```

El XML que obtiene ese campo es el siguiente:

```
<ntext4>;#Alexander Pierce;#Sarah Ross;#Adam Jones;#</ntext4>
<nvarchar1>TICKET DE PRUEBA</nvarchar1>
<nvarchar4>Iniciada</nvarchar4>
```

El valor que me interesa obtener en mi consulta y con el cual obtengo error es el que se encuentra entre las etiquetas `<ntext4></ntext4>`, desconozco si hay otra manera de obtener estos valores desde un XML o me hace falta realizar algún `CAST` o `CONVERT` para los tipos de datos.

Comment: El problema está en el join, pareciera. Estás igualando`ASG.tp_ID = T.AsignadoSG` y es ahí donde estarías intentando comparar un INT (supongo) y el texto (que estás recuperando sin lío y es varchar, como lo dice el error)

Answer (score 0):

Es tan fácil como convertir los tipos de datos al tipo correcto. El problema es que la conversión implicita que estás viendo sigue las reglas de precedencia de datos, por lo que las cadenas casi siempre se convierten a otros tipos.

Puedes cambiar todo a cadena

```
SELECT T.Titulo     Titulo,
            ASG.AsignadoSG AsignadoSG,
            ASG.tp_ID ClaveAsignadoSG
    FROM        (Select tp_ColumnSet.value('(/nvarchar1)[1]', 'nvarchar(100)') Titulo,
                        tp_ColumnSet.value('(/nvarchar4)[1]', 'nvarchar(100)') Estado,                      
                        tp_ColumnSet.value('(/ntext4)[1]', 'varchar(max)')  AsignadoSG
                From WSS_Content.dbo.UserData   
                Where tp_ListId = 'C4B4B8A8' )  T
    LEFT JOIN (SELECT tp_ID,
            tp_ColumnSet.value('(/nvarchar1)[1]', 'nvarchar(100)') AsignadoSG 
            FROM WSS_Content.DBO.UserData WHERE tp_ListId = '176A5B63') ASG ON CAST( ASG.tp_ID AS varchar(max)) = T.AsignadoSG     
    Where   T.Estado in ('Iniciada', 'En Curso')
```

Pero teniendo un dato tan largo puede generar problemas de rendimiento adicionales. Tal vez pueda funcionar convirtiendo a entero y descartando cualquier cosa que no sea entero.

```
SELECT T.Titulo     Titulo,
            ASG.AsignadoSG AsignadoSG,
            ASG.tp_ID ClaveAsignadoSG
    FROM        (Select tp_ColumnSet.value('(/nvarchar1)[1]', 'nvarchar(100)') Titulo,
                        tp_ColumnSet.value('(/nvarchar4)[1]', 'nvarchar(100)') Estado,                      
                        tp_ColumnSet.value('(/ntext4)[1]', 'varchar(max)')  AsignadoSG
                From WSS_Content.dbo.UserData   
                Where tp_ListId = 'C4B4B8A8' )  T
    LEFT JOIN (SELECT tp_ID,
            tp_ColumnSet.value('(/nvarchar1)[1]', 'nvarchar(100)') AsignadoSG 
            FROM WSS_Content.DBO.UserData WHERE tp_ListId = '176A5B63') ASG ON ASG.tp_ID =  TRY_CAST( T.AsignadoSG AS int)    
    Where   T.Estado in ('Iniciada', 'En Curso')
```

Comment: Parece ser que no puedo usar `TRY_CAST` estoy obteniendo como mensaje de error lo siguiente `'TRY_CAST' is not a recognized built-in function name.` la versión de SQLServer que utilizo es 2008 R2

Comment: Parece que ese es un problema común en estos días. Eso lo acaban de preguntar hace unos días y lo mejor será que conviertas a cadena en vez de tratar de convertir a entero.